# Wacom Tablet or Lemur (ipad) for sound design

Tags: sound-design, gear

I would like to design some crazy sounds like WALL-E with a tablet.I have a dilemma whether to invest on a wacom tablet or an ipad with lemur app. Which one is the best buy? kindly help...

Comment: for us to answer this with some satisfaction, please explain if you already have an ipad. if not wacom is much cheaper... btw a midikeyboard with xy parameters is also used on these types of projects: google wall e sound design ben burtt

Comment: I dont have an ipad + its expensive aswell - now wacom or any midi controller is the choice for me - do u know or have used any midi controller with xy pads which are good? Thanks Arnoud

Comment: no sorry cannot help you with that :(

Answer (score 2):

the only extra dimension you get with a Wacom tablet is pressure, but you also don't get all the cool midi interface things that come with Lemur, like physics, randomization etc. Basically its apples and oranges.

Personally, I'd say go with the Lemur app, as it has much more OTB functionality.